# Walk/Fly navigation Blender 3.2

Tags: shortcut, navigation

I just updated my version of Blender on Steam to the new version 3.2, the problem is that I use a lot the walk mode and it doesn't work (Shift F).
I looked in the preferences-Keymap but I can't find the option to assign the keys.
Can someone help me?
also nothing appears if I type "walk" or "fly" it's as if the option to assign the keys has disappeared (yes, I know that from View-Navigation-Walk Navigation I can access this mode but that does not solve my problem of not being able to assign the keys as I have always done)[image].

Comment: Try downloading from the blender website? Or if you're using MS from the Microsoft store?

Comment: I tried to export the shorcuts from blender 3.1 and then put them in blender 3.2 but it didn't work, I tried to download it from the Blender page and it didn't work either, it's as if they had removed that option, it's really weird.

Comment: They have not removed the option and if I type 'view n' in the search box I find a keymap entry, although it is set to shift-` (backtick/accent grave).  If you search for "view3d.navigate" with the F3 search, does it show up?

Comment: I didn't see anything like this change in the release notes. https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2 Try loading the factory defaults from File->Defaults->Load Factory Settings

Comment: It worked with factory defaults, thanks!